# Steering a car in CoronaSDK

Tags: iphone, ipad, lua, coronasdk

Having a bit on an issue, what I want to achieve is a car that is drivable with a D-Pad. I am attempting physics joints on all 4 corners of the "frame" of the car. Then each "wheel" is applied a force to move it forward and backwards. Simple enough I think, can't even get the wheels to stay attached. I weld them to it, but then it won't move.

Second, steering?! How on earth is this accomplished?

Thank you very much, been stressed over getting it to work!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is helpful, but here's a link that may push you in the right direction: http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2009/04/06/two-ways-to-make-box2d-cars/. This is an example of what I believe you are looking for, but it's in AS3. However, it's using Box2D physics which is what the CoronaSDK uses. Should be able to translate.

Answer (score 0):

Weld joins don't allow any kind of movement.  Pivot joints would be a better choice and more realistic.  As for the steering, if this is a top down game, you probably should apply force to the front region of the car and not each wheel as it could do weird things.